# jQuery $.each - Specifying which object/sub-object you are referring to?

Tags: jquery, json

I asked a similar question about this before, and although my code worked (then), I didn't understand what was going on.

My function:

```
function matchesfill(){
    $.each(json.result.matches, function(i, v) {
        if (i.lobby_type == 7){
            matches[x] = i.match_id;
            x=x+1;
            console.log('match added to array');
        }
        else{
            console.log('match skipped: non-ranked');
        }
        });
        return;
}
```

Currently, when run, the console just logs `match skipped` for all, even though this is incorrect. It should be only 1 of the matches are to be skipped.

and the jSON:

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_results": 10,
        "total_results": 500,
        "results_remaining": 490,
        "matches": [
            {
                "match_id": 515853415,
                "match_seq_num": 469991846,
                "start_time": 1392156202,
                "lobby_type": 7,
                "players": [
```

Edit: I apologise, I read the documentation and I understand what they mean, but I still do not understand why my code is not working.

Thank you in advance for being patient with a new learner.

Comment: *"So when you make a $.each function, and you specify function(i v), what does the i refer to, and the v"*. That's precisely the kind of question the documentation answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered by the standard documentation

Comment: `i` is the index (for an array) or the key (for an object), `v` is the value - be that an actual value (a string, number, boolean, etc.), an object or another array. You want to be using `v`, not `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in documentation, `i` is index and `v` is value so you must use `v`.

```
if (v.lobby_type == 7)
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I see. I looked at the documentation, as I neglected to do before. (I apologise!) 

So v.lobby_type refers to the value (7), what does i.lobby_type refer to, the index? What is the index of an object that is underneath other objects?

Comment: Variable `i` contains just the index of the item in the array (0, 1, 2, ...) . `i.lobby_type` is not defined.